# Why randn doesn't always have a mean of 0 and variance of 1?

Tags: python, random, pytorch, tensor

For the [PyTorch.randn()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=randn#torch.randn) method the documentation says:

> Returns a tensor filled with random numbers from a normal distribution
>   with mean `0` and variance `1` (also called the standard normal
>   distribution).

So here is an example tensor:

```
x = torch.randn(4,3)
tensor([[-0.6569, -0.7337, -0.0028],
        [-0.3938,  0.3223,  0.0497],
        [ 0.0129, -2.7546, -2.2488],
        [ 1.6754, -0.1497,  1.8202]])
```

When I print the mean:

```
x.mean()
tensor(-0.2550)
```

When I print the standard deviation:

```
x.std()
tensor(1.3225)
```

So why isn't the mean 0 and the standard deviation 1?

Bonus question: How do I generate a random tensor that always has a mean of 0?

Comment: The distribution generating your (12) samples is defined to have mean 0 and std 1. What you are calculating is sample mean and sample variance which tend, especially for small sample sizes, to not equal the true mean and std. You may take a look at this wikipedia article: [Sample mean and covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance)

Comment: A die roll has a mean of 3.5. That doesn't mean if you throw a die ten times that the numbers you rolled will have an average of 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be a big coincidence that a finite sample of the distribution has **exactly** the same mean and **exactly** the same standard deviation. It is to be expected that the more numbers you generate, the closer the mean and deviation of the sample approaches the "true" mean and deviation of the distribution.

Comment: Yeah, asking for a std of 1 was probably a little dumb, but is it possible to generate a small random tensor with a mean of 0?

Comment: @Reactgular Not if the samples are supposed to be IID.

Comment: @Reactgular No, mean of sample of gaussians has a distribution - it is a gaussian as well with the same mean and stddev = sigma/sqrt(n). Cannot be equal to any exact number

Answer (score 3):

I can only answer half of this: I think you've misunderstood the documentation. It should not be parsed as "Returns a tensor {filled with random numbers from a normal distribution} with mean 0 and variance 1" but as "Returns a tensor filled with {random numbers from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1}". I.e. the returned tensor does not have mean 0 or variance 1. It's only the distribution from which the random numbers are drawn that has mean 0 and variance 1.

Answer (score 2):

if you really want a given sample to have a mean of zero and variance of 1 (as opposed to being sampled from a distribution with zero mean and unit variance) then you can just transform it to make it so, e.g.:

```
x = torch.randn(4,3)
x -= x.mean()
x /= x.std()
```

this sort of thing can be useful

Comment: this is nonsense, what kind of distribution is it? It is definitely NOT a mean of gaussians

Comment: what sort of distribution is what?  there are lots of distributions involved here.  formally, `x` will end up t-distributed, but given the question I'm not sure if the distinction matters.  much more important is the distinction between a distribution's parameters and the summary statistics of a given sample

Comment: `mean`  means `Sum(N(0,1))/n` which, in itself, is some random variable following some DISTRIBUTION. And, as you could read in any reasonable statistics book, it is a gaussian one. Fixing mean and stddev means distribution of that sum changed. What is it?